# Kohana 3.1: Calling a controller from within another; not returning data

Tags: kohana-3

I just can't seem to get my head wrapped around this... I have a few questions, please bear with me! :)

First, the setup:
I have a controller (controllerA) which extends Controller_Template. Inside controllerA's template view I have jQuery tabs which AJAX-loads another controller (controllerB). And then I have a "core" controller which contains functions that I reuse within other controllers (well, I would LIKE TO anyway).

Now for my questions:

**1.** Is it okay (best practice) to be loading the jQuery tab contents like I mentioned above, with:
    `<li><a href="/controller">test</a></li>`?

**2.** In JS and PHP I've always had a 'core' file for reusable code. Is there a better alternative to doing it this way? Should I instead have my core extend Controller and then extend all my controllers off of that? I'm concerned about the overhead though.

**3.** Last, if I call the core with `Request::factory()->execute()->response()`, I get nothing back unless I use something like `die($data)` instead of `return $data` it. But if I call that function from within another in the core, it won't work. How can I make it work across the board?

Thanks for your help, as always!

Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use [reverse routing](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/routing#creating-urls-and-links-using-routes) to generate
   project URIs. Or you will modify all 
   of your views after changing in routing rules.
2. Extend Controller_Template in your
   basic controller class - it will be
   parent class for all other
   controllers.
3. `Request::factory()->execute()->response()`
   returns string, so you need at least
   `echo`. And dont forget to set
   $this->request->response in your
   ajax method.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the advice. So if I extend Controller_Template with my core class, that would pretty much eliminate my need for using Request::factory(), wouldn't it? I could just then reference it as $this->function, correct? Many thanks!

Comment: I followed your advice on the routing and it works like a champ! I also ended up extending Controller with my Controller_Core and then just extending that with my other controllers as needed. Works like a dream! However, could you give me an example of what you mean about setting $this->request->response in my ajax method? I'm afraid I don't understand what I need to do with that. Thanks!!

Comment: Sorry, my third point was about HMVC, not AJAX. If your AJAX call returns nothing, it can be error with data formatting. For example, jQuery's `$.post()` function has a 'format' param, so your application response can be ecnoded incorrectly. You should debug AJAX call with firebug, its a greatest webmaster tool.